# moment and datetimepicker are not working after gulp bundling

Tags: angularjs, gulp, momentjs, gulp-concat, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I used moment.js and [datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) in my code, after bundling all these js files together, the website(in angularjs-1.6.4) is not loading properly.

I am using gulp to bundle all related js files to a vendor.bundle.js, this is bundling task

```
gulp.task('vendorbundle', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.src([
            config.node_module_dir + '/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            config.node_module_dir + '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
            config.node_module_dir + '/moment/moment.js',
            config.node_module_dir + '/angular/angular.js',
            config.node_module_dir + '/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            config.node_module_dir + '/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
            config.node_module_dir + '/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
            config.node_module_dir + '/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
            config.node_module_dir + '/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.js',
            config.node_module_dir + '/bootstrap-table/src/extensions/angular/bootstrap-table-angular.js',
            config.node_module_dir + '/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js',
            config.node_module_dir + '/angular-eonasdan-datetimepicker/dist/angular-eonasdan-datetimepicker.js'
        ]).on('error', function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        })
        .pipe(concat('vendor.bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }));
});
```

Am I missing any?